# How to display a list of nodes in a block?

Tags: nodes, 8, blocks

I have a custom block and I want to output a list of nodes of a certain type.

This is what I have so far:

```
public function build() {

$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'my_content_type')
  ->execute();

$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadMultiple($nids);

    return array(
      '#markup' => $this->t('How to display list here'),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I list the nodes by title and ordered by newest at the bottom of list?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a specific issue not mentioned in the question, I would recommend using a view to create this block. This would mean that the criteria remained easily editable.

If you had specific need to output the list of nodes within a custom block, or would like to pass arguments to the view from custom code you could use [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.module/function/views_embed_view/8.2.x).